# How to redirect the directory list file to 404 custom web page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, windows-server

Recently I noticed that if I browse a link based on my wordpress server directory listing,

-Eg: https://website.com/examples, it will show error message forbidden.

-Eg: https://website.com/wp-admin/* , it will show error message access denied page.

I had try to redirect the link to 404 page in .htaccess file.

`RewriteRule ^wp-admin/* /index.php?wph-throw-404 [L]`

It works but this also affect to the files of the sub folders in the Myfolders like css/javascript and cause I cannot login to my wordpress and webpage lost the images and everything are mess up.

Is that anyway can prevent this happen and also fix the problem I faced?

Comment: A side note, meant as additional help for you: whilst `^Myfolders/*` is a valid regex pattern it does _not_ express what you apparently think. Regular expressions do _not_ support an asterisk ("*") as a wildcard. That character has a completely different meaning in regular expressions! You probably want to use the optional operator for such situations ("?", so `^Myfolders/?$` or `^Myfolders(?:/.+)/?$`).

Comment: Well, i tried your code, it were work for few folders to direct to 404, but it also make my  wordpress show server error......

Comment: You should not blindly copy something you read somewhere on the internet. You need to _understand_ 1. what you are told and 2. how the tools you are trying to use work. If you don't then we cannot help.

Comment: Never mind, i had find another method that completely fulfill what i want. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the rewrite rule in a way that it only redirects directory access attempts to the 404 page, try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Myfolders
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: I had tried your way but not work for me. I update my post just for your to know what exactly are the folders i mention